# How do I change widget in subthread (Raspbian)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, guizero

I am writing a python code under Raspbian. I want to enable my button after taking a video, but it doesn't work, as I get an error message after I press the button. Please see my code below.

```
def doit():
   *here take 5 minutes video and save*
    start_video_button.enable()      #NOT WORKING
   
start_video_button.disable()
t = threading.Thread(target=doit)
t.start()
```

I appreciate any help I can get.

Kind regards,
ml

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error, does it fail to execute, unexpected behavior, etc? It will help others give you a more direct and helpful answer.

Comment: I receive an error message after I press the button.